# Umbraco cannot browse page by pagename.aspx

Tags: umbraco

I have two seperate clean installations of Umbraco 4.5.x and both are having similar problems with page handling. If I browse pages by ID like /1083.aspx the page displays correctly, but if I try to browse by name like /about-us.aspx it gives 404 - file or directory not found.

Thanks in advance.

Sanjay

Comment: This is now resolved. It turned out to be issues with the content structure. The root file/folder need to first item in content hierarchy and all other nodes should be child.

Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

Sanjay,

This is because when you're hunting for root content nodes, the umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath appSetting in the web.config is set to true by default.
As the name might imply, this hides the top-level node from the URL path. You can set it to "false" to override this behaviour.

HTH,

Benjamin